# Folding 3-variate function with 2 iterator

Tags: iterators, functional

I have a function say $f$ and some initial point $x$ and pairs of iterators
$\{\{a_1,b_1\},\{a_2,b_2\},...\}$

I want to foldlist as follows:
$\{x,f[x,a_1,b_1],f[f[x,a_1,b_1],a_2,b_2],...\}$

can somebody suggest a builtin function to do this or a fast algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go using FoldList

```
list = Array[{Subscript[a, #], Subscript[b, #]} &, {3, 1}] // 
  Flatten /@ # &  (* or Flatten[#,1]& doing the same, but faster *) 

FoldList[f[#, Sequence @@ #2]&, x, list]
```

[image]

EDIT, according suggestion from Shutao Tang to create the initial list in a more elegant and efficient way:

```
list={Subscript[a, #], Subscript[b, #]} & /@ Range[3]
```

Comment: Why not `list={Subscript[a, #], Subscript[b, #]} & /@ Range[3]` directly?

Comment: @Shutao Tang, ....because penguins are not always as smart as you, thx for your comment.

Comment: We can learn each other .:)